# How to concatenate a string and a list?

Tags: python, string

I have a list and a string:

```
fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'plum']
mystr = 'i like the following fruits: '
```

How can I concatenate them so I get

```
'i like the following fruits: banana, apple, plum'
```

Keep in mind that the enum may change size.

Answer (score 28):

Join the list, then add the strings.

```
print mystr + ', '.join(fruits)
```

And don't use the name of a built-in type (`str`) as a variable name.

Answer (score 11):

You can use this code,

```
fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'plum', 'pineapple', 'cherry']
mystr = 'i like the following fruits: '
print (mystr + ', '.join(fruits))
```

The above code will return the output as below:

```
i like the following fruits: banana, apple, plum, pineapple, cherry
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

```
result = "i like the following fruits: "+', '.join(fruits)
```

(assuming `fruits` only contains strings).  If `fruits` contains a non-string, you can convert it easily by creating a generator expression on the fly:

```
', '.join(str(f) for f in fruits)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have a problem if you name your variables the same as Python built-ins. Otherwise this would work:

```
s = s + ', '.join([str(fruit) for fruit in fruits])
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple code below will work:

```
print(mystr, fruits)
```