# Concatenate a string and a list

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python concatenate string & list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633024/python-concatenate-string-list)

Is it possible to concatenate a string and a list?

The following code causes the error: `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`

```
t = ["a", "b", "c"]
s = "%s.%s.%s" % t
```

Comment: The `arguments` (here `t`) has to be a single argument or a tuple of arguments. Such, the list is taken as a single argument (try `'%s' % ['sample', 'format']`)

Comment: need convert list to tuple. Then it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That could work if you convert your list to tuple like this:

```
t = ["a", "b", "c"]
s = "%s.%s.%s" % tuple(t)
```

But, python strings has the built in method .join, so, if your list grows, you can handle it like this:

```
'.'.join(t)
```

That's the "pythonic way", you also should avoid using the + operator with strings, always use .join and format strings. This is because Python Strings (and tuples) are not mutable objects, so, when you're doing

```
"abc" + "cde"
```

Python has to allocate new memory to store the new string.

I hope this solved your question

Comment: While everything you said is true, `+` is reasonably efficient in recent versions of Python, and will be faster for a small number of strings.

Comment: Really? I've never profiled it, do you have any benchmark/blog-post to read about that?. In python 3 a lot of things are more efficient, starting with the intensive use of iterators instead of plain lists, but Python 2 still being the standard :(. Thank you for the information

Comment: See http://greaterdebater.com/blog/gabe/post/7 or http://web.archive.org/web/20110711182729/http://sprocket.io/blog/2007/10/string-concatenation-performance-in-python/ for example. I don't remember exactly, but I think this dates back to at least Python 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're trying to do, the [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method would be the solution:

```
'.'.join(t)
>>> "a.b.c"
```

Answer (score 0):

what if u just

t[0]+t[1]...+t ?

Comment: This works but it is inefficient because of how python handles it with strings. Using format strings or `join` is much cleaner and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it with new string formatting:

```
t = ["a", "b", "c"]
s = "{}.{}.{}".format(*t)
```