# Combining 4 URL parts using python

Tags: python

I think this has a simple answer, but I haven't been able to crack it. Say you have a URL that needs to be broken down into four parts:

```
comp1 = 'www.base.com/'
comp2 = list1   # a list of letters, say "AAA", "BBB", "CCC"
comp3 = list2   # another list, but this time dates: '2019/10/21', '2019/10/20', '2019/10/19'
comp4 = "/example.html"
```

I have tried to combine these in multiple different ways, and I know `urllib.parse.urljoin` is the best option, but it cannot take more than three arguments:

```
for i in comp2:
    iter1 = urllib.parse.urljoin(comp1, i)
    print(iter1)  # this pairs the first two components nicely

for j in comp3:
    iter2 = urllib.parse.urljoin(j, comp4)
    print(iter2)  # this just returns '/example.html', and nothing is joined
```

What's the most pythonic way to join these 4 components? I've tried `''.join()`, but that only takes one argument. I'm going to have a lot more than just three iterations. In `R`, I would just slam my components in a `paste0()` and call it a night.

Comment: do you want your end result to be: `www.base.com/AAABBBCCC/2019/10/212019/10/20/example.html`  if you can provide exactly what you are looking for it will help get an answer. :)  It looks like you are just trying to combine strings and lists, maybe this will help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633024/python-concatenate-string-list

Comment: `reduce` in combination with `urljoin` seems like a good option, see [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/175423).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right to want to use `''.join()`, but you are misunderstanding the argument... it should be any iterable (a list, a tuple, or similar). You can create an iterable on the fly by just putting the items in a list or tuple directly:

```
result = ''.join([comp1, comp2, comp3])
```

Of course, this assumes that each item in the list is itself a single string element. If `comp2` and `comp3` are already lists, you may need to also do joins to get them where you want them:

```
result = ''.join([
    comp1,
    '/'.join(comp2),
    '/'.join(comp3),
    comp4,
])
```

If you're using modern versions of Python (not Python 2.x) you can also format strings very nicely using `f-strings`:

```
result = f'www.base.com/{comp2}/{comp3}/example.html'
```

Note here, too, that you may need to do additional formatting if `comp2` and `comp3` are lists:

```
result = f'www.base.com/{"/".join(comp2)}/{"/".join(comp3)}/example.html'
```

In that case, make sure the quotes you use on the `join` strings are different than the quotes on the outer `f-string` or are properly escaped.

Answer (score 1):

Going off of your example

you can do something like this:

```
for x in comp2:
      for y in comp3:
          combine = comp1 + x + y + comp4
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this isn't exactly what you want, but if it really is just jamming the string and lists together, this would work:

```
comp1 = 'www.base.com/'
comp2 = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"]
comp3 = ['2019/10/21', '2019/10/20', '2019/10/19']
comp4 = "/example.html"


url = comp1 + "".join(comp2) + "".join(comp3) + comp4

print (url)
```

results:

`www.base.com/AAABBBCCC2019/10/212019/10/202019/10/19/example.html`

You can fiddle with the `""` in the `join` to make it toss in `/` or whatever delimiter you'd want for the items in the list.  Perhaps you want `AAA/BBB` for example.  So you would do `"/".join([comp2])` instead.

The deal with `join` only taking 1 argument is it only takes a `list`, but that `list` can be made up of a bunch of stuff.  Good luck :)

Comment: I'm aiming to scrape data, so iterating through the `AAA` to `BBB` plus the dates in their own individual links. I'll update the question to reflect that, but something like this: `www.base.com/AAA/2010/10/21/example.html`

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

```
def _url(r, *path_components):
    for c in path_components:
        r += "/{}".format(str(c))    
    return r
```